# Given set $A = \{x \in \mathbb{R} | x >0\}$ prove that the set doesn't have a neutral element

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

> Given set $A = \{x \in \mathbb{R} | x >0\}$ an $\oplus$ action is defined on the set: $x \oplus y = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}$ such that $x, y \in A$. Is there a neutral (identity) element for the relation?

In my understanding there's not a neutral element for the relation but I'm new to this topic so I would like to know if my proof is correct:

an element $e$ is neutral if $e \in A$ and for all $x \in A$ we have:

$x \oplus e = e \oplus x = x$  so $x \oplus e = \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{e}=\frac{1}{x} \Rightarrow\frac{1}{e} = 0$ which is undefined so we don't have a neutral element. Should I also have pointed out that $0 \notin A$?

Comment: you have that $x \oplus e = x$, which translates to $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{e} = x$ instead of what you wrote. Anyway, you clearly have that $1 \in A$, so we would need that $1 \oplus e = 1$, which is equivalent to 1 + \frac{1}{e} = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality $x \oplus e = x$ translates as $\dfrac 1 x + \dfrac 1 e = x$. Take $x=1$, for instance: you get then that $1 + \dfrac 1 e = 1$, i.e. $\dfrac 1 e = 0$, and there is no such real number $e$. Your idea was correct, you just made a little mistake when applying it.

Comment: So for an element not to be neutral we just need to show at least one example of where this doesn't happen right?

Comment: So why do we have the requirement $x>0$ then? The argument here does not seem to use it.

Comment: @Yos: Not always; the approach above was the simplest strategy in this problem. There is no general method of showing that a given law does not have a neutral element.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Indeed, $x>0$ is not needed here, but I believe that the given law has other properties that would fail if $A$ contained an $y<0$. For instance, one would end up dividing by $0$ when writing $x \oplus (y \oplus (-y))$ if one wanted to test associativity.

Comment: @AlexM. you're right there were other questions on this set including associativity. By the way, does your example mean that associativity doesn't hold for the relation because $(y \oplus -y) \notin A$?

Comment: @Yos: In order to give associativity a chance, $A$ was restricted to be $(0, \infty)$. This is the explanation of the disappearance of the negative numbers from $A$.

Comment: More generally, $\oplus$ wouldn't be closed on the set $B = \{x \in \mathbb R \mid x \ne 0\}$, since $x \oplus -x = 0 \notin B$, and wouldn't be well-defined on all of $\mathbb R$, since $x \oplus 0$ would involve division by $0$. The set $A$ is the biggest set (or at least, *one* biggest set) on which we can have the operation $\oplus$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

take $x=1$ so that $x \oplus e=x$ becomes $1 +\frac{1} {e}=1$.